# Counting file in a directory

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I want to count number of file in a directory, I used count method in QDir class but it always return number of file plus two! why does it do this work ?
thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`QDir.count()` returns the total count of files and directories in the directory. This includes the `.` (this) and `..` (parent) directory entries. So the count is always two more than the "real" files and subdirectories.

Comment: Not "always". See [Alok Save's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6890792/10147399).

Answer (score 14):

You should use `flags QDir::Filters` with `QDir::NoDotAndDotDot`

Answer (score 12):

I am posting a complete answer.

```
QString path = "c:\test"; // assume it is some path

QDir dir( path );

dir.setFilter( QDir::AllEntries | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot );

int total_files = dir.count();
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll need exclude `.` and `..` - `QDir::Files` filter can help you there.

Relevant docs:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdir.html#entryList
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdir.html#Filter-enum

Answer (score 0):

You Can use :

```cpp
QFileInfo fileInfo(m_logFilePath);
QDir dir(fileInfo.absoluteDir());
QStringList totalfiles;
totalfiles = dir.entryList(QStringList("*"), QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks);
```

using file name

```cpp
totalfiles = dir.entryList(QStringList("filename"), QDir::Files | QDir::Names);
```