# How to fast count large set of files

Tags: qt, qdir

As I have to process a large number of files, I'd like to show a progress of this process.

I know that iterating using `QDirIterator::next()` is the best option, but first I need to know the total number of files in a directory (and all its subdirectories).

What is the fastest method to count a large set of files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting file in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890757/counting-file-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code to count all files and directories inside "opt" folder

```
QDir dir("/opt/");
dir.count();
```

Use below code to list *.jpg files  in current and all its subdirectories.

```
QDirIterator it("/opt/", QStringList() << "*.jpg", QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
int count = 0;
while (it.hasNext()){
    qDebug() << it.next();
    count++;
}
qDebug() << "count:" << count;
```

Comment: Thx. But I didn't mention one detail: I need to count only files with given extention... For example count all *.jpg in directory and its all subdirectories.

Comment: I hoped that there is faster method to find the number of files with given extension, however thank you a lot for your time!